# laravel: how to disable timestamps when using attach() with many to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel

Tables:

```
Gift: id, name  
User: id, name  
GiftUser: gift_id, user_id, count
```

In `GiftUser` model, I already have this line

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

In migration seeder:

```
foreach ($all_gifts as $key => $gift) {
  $gift_user = GiftUser::where('gift_id', $gift['id'])->where('user_id', $user->id)->first();

  if(empty($gift_user)){
    $user->gifts()->attach($gift['id'], ['count' => 1]);
  }else{
    $user->gifts()->updateExistingPivot($gift, ['count' => ($gift_user->count+1)]);
  }
}
```

This `foreach` is to add a `gift_user record`. For each gift, if the user doesn't have, add a new record. If the user already has the gift, `count+1`.

But when executing the seeder, it says

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'created_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `gift_user` (
>       `count`, `created_at`, `gift_id`, `updated_at`, `user_id`) values (1, 2018-04-11 13:49:14, 2, 2018-04-11 13:49:14,
>       1))
>
> In Connection.php line 452:
>
> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'created_at' in 'field list'

When the two columns created_at and updated_at exist, it's ok.
But now I don't want those two columns.

I guess, when using `attach()` and `updateExistingPivot()`, `GiftUser` model seems not used, right? How to fix it?

Comment: then u have to remove it from table and migration also. or u can send in created_at current timestamp

Comment: It's already removed from table and migration. The problem is, no such columns, but seeder tries to insert.

Comment: share your seeder code

Comment: I already shared my seeder code when I ask this question!!!!

Answer (score 0):

something its wrong, so my answer is not a solution, just a quickfix (maybe)

try to guard this fields inside a model:

```
protected $guarded = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
```